# Como é que posso por essas perguntas aleatorias?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class responder : MonoBehaviour {

    private int idTema;

    public Text pergunta;
    public Text RespostaA;
    public Text RespostaB;
    public Text RespostaC;
    public Text RespostaD;
    public Text infoRespostas;


    public string[] perguntas;
    public string[] alternativaA;
    public string[] alternativaB;
    public string[] alternativaC;
    public string[] alternativaD;
    public string[] corretas;

    private int idPergunta;

    private float acertos;
    private float questoes;
    private float media;
    private int notaFinal;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        idTema = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("idTema");
        idPergunta = 0;
        questoes = perguntas.Length;
        pergunta.text = perguntas [idPergunta];
        RespostaA.text = alternativaA [idPergunta];
        RespostaB.text = alternativaB [idPergunta];
        RespostaC.text = alternativaC [idPergunta];
        RespostaD.text = alternativaD [idPergunta];
        infoRespostas.text = "Respondendo "+(idPergunta + 1).ToString()+ " de "+questoes.ToString()+"perguntas.";
    }
    public void resposta(string alternativa)
    {
        if (alternativa == "A") 
        {
            if (alternativaA [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta]) 
            {
                acertos += 1;
            }
        } 
        else if (alternativa == "B") 
        {
            if (alternativaB [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta]) 
            {
                acertos += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (alternativa == "C") 
        {
            if (alternativaC [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta]) 
            {
                acertos += 1;
            }
        }   
        else if (alternativa == "D") 
        {
            if (alternativaD [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta]) 
            {
                acertos += 1;
            }
        }
        proximaPergunta ();
    }
    void proximaPergunta()
    {
        idPergunta += 1;

        if (idPergunta <= (questoes - 1)) 
        {
            pergunta.text = perguntas [idPergunta];
            RespostaA.text = alternativaA [idPergunta];
            RespostaB.text = alternativaB [idPergunta];
            RespostaC.text = alternativaC [idPergunta];
            RespostaD.text = alternativaD [idPergunta];
            infoRespostas.text = "Respondendo " + (idPergunta + 1).ToString () + " de " + questoes.ToString () + "perguntas.";
        }
        else 
        {
            media = 10 * (acertos / questoes);
            notaFinal = Mathf.RoundToInt (media);

            if (notaFinal > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("notaFinal" + idTema.ToString ())) 
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("notaFinal" + idTema.ToString (), notaFinal);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("acertos" + idTema.ToString (), (int) acertos);
            }
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("notaFinalTemp" + idTema.ToString (), notaFinal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("acertosTemp" + idTema.ToString (), (int) acertos);
            Application.LoadLevel ("nota");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Onde quer fazer isto? Tem algum critério? Quais são as perguntas? A pergunta não está nada clara.

Comment: Olá David. Edite a questão para explicar o seu código. Explique o que são as perguntas, o que você deseja fazer e, principalmente, onde exatamente está a sua dificuldade (por exemplo, você não sabe como gerar um número aleatório em C#? ou não sabe como garantir que ele esteja entre 0 e o máximo de um array/lista de perguntas? etc).

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se isso vai ser útil pra você. Mas mostro a baixo um exemplo de como deixar uma coleção (List,Array) aleatório.

**Chamada do Método**

```
public void RandomizarMinhaLista()
{
    List<string> foo = new List<string>();
    foo.Add("foo1");
    foo.Add("foo2");
    foo.Add("foo3");

    var fooRandomizado = foo.Randomize();
    //Ou
    var fooRandomizado2 = RandomizeArray.Randomize(foo);
}
```

**Classe estática**

```
public static class RandomizeArray
{
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    public static IEnumerable<TModel> Randomize<TModel>(this IEnumerable<TModel> collection)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, TModel>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, TModel>>();

        // Insere todos os items da coleção em uma nova lista.
        foreach (TModel s in collection)
        {
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, TModel>(_random.Next(), s));
        }
        // Randomiza a lista
        var sorted = from item in list
                        orderby item.Key
                        select item;

        // Aloca um array de TModel
        TModel[] result = new TModel[collection.ToArray().Length];
        // Copia os valores para o array.
        int index = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, TModel> pair in sorted)
        {
            result[index] = pair.Value;
            index++;
        }
        // Retorna array copiado.
        return result;
    }
}
```